# Degrees of irreducible characters of groups of order 48

Tags: characters, finite-groups

Hello

i wonder if there is a simple argument to show that no group of order 48 can have an irreducible character of degree larger than 4?

Thanks, Karim

Comment: Edited to change 6 to 4 per karim's clarification.

Comment: All groups of order 48 are well known, so the question is similar to "why 2 times 3 is 6?" (in fact it is equivalent to a small number of such questions). Voted to close. 

Comment: Just an easy observation: the only possibility would be $\chi(1)=6$, which implies $\ker\chi$ is trivial, so you have a faithful irreducible character.

Comment: I wonder whether it's an interesting question to ask for groups of order $n$ with an irreducible character of degree $d$ with $(d+1)^2\ge n$? The group $A_4$, of order 12, has an irreducible character of degree 3; there's a group of order 20 with an irrep of degree 4, and a group of order 42 with an irrep of degree 6. 

Comment: @Mark is right.  Why bother asking questions about any group of order less than 2000?


Comment: @Gerry: They have been known for a while.  See http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0603239

Comment: @Steve D: I am not sure you understand what you are saying. There are
4725 groups of order 864, for example, and you need a CAS to treat them. There are only 52 groups of order 48, and you can treat them by hand. Each one of them has a normal subgroup of order 16 or 8. In the first case, it is an extension of a group of order 16 by a group of order 3, in the second case it is an extension of a group of order 8 by $S_3$. Also not every question about a small group is trivial. For example, construct a hyperbolic 6-manifold with isometry group $S_3$, if you can (hint: it can be done).  

Comment: @Mark: So when you said "well known", you meant you could list all of them by hand? And many others could too? I did not know that.

Comment: Knowing a lot about a small group, even its character table, does not mean that you can't ask for a "conceptual" explanation of why some things happen. I agree that this particular question is not research level, but it requires some thought to explain the phenomenon from a theoretical perspective.

Comment: Since it not possible to answer, I will at least point out that ths can be done as a good exercise in applying Clifford's theorem and orthogonality relations.

Comment: @Steve D: Google "groups of order 48". The cite http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Groups_of_order_48 and http://www.math.niu.edu/~beachy/abstract_algebra/study_guide/soln74.html#s7415 (homework exercise) contains all you may want to know about these groups. Yes, these groups can be listed on one A4 piece of paper. 